# In C++, we can't declare a reference without initialization. Why?

Tags: c++, binding, reference

In C++, we can't declare a reference without initialization. What is the actual reason for this.Although we are aware about the uses of references in operator overloading and other concepts.

Comment: _"Is there any logical reason for this ...."_ Think twice dude, before asking such. What should an uninitialized reference refer to actually?

Comment: You can't reassign references, so it would be kind of pointless if it weren't initialized.

Comment: Because otherwise it wouldn't be a reference, it would be a pointer.

Comment: A reference is always supposed to refer to a valid object, therefore it must be initialized as such.  Meanwhile, a pointer can be NULL.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What does an uninitialized pointer point to?

Answer (score 4):

C++ references (in the ordinary C++ meaning of that word) can't be reassigned. So if a reference isn't initialized it can't be made to refer to anything. And the language does not support null-references, hence, an uninitialized reference, if such were permitted, would always be in error.

Answer (score 1):

C++ references are actually pointers in disguise, but they lead to cleaner code. A reference can only refer to a single object(it can't be reassigned to something else). A C++ reference can't be `null`. Then think of how it can be uninitialized.

A reference behaves like a value type, and that is another reason why it can't be null. Consider it just as an alias for another variable.

```
int a = 3;
int& b = a;
auto c = b; // When you use references in such expressions, 
            // it behaves exactly like substituting the referred variable.
```

Here `c` is not a reference to `a` or `b`, instead it is of type `int`. The value is copied from `a` to `c`.

The above code is equivalent to,

```
int a = 3;
int c = a;
```

In C, which doesn't support references, the above code is written as,

```
int a = 3;
int* b = a;
int c = *b;
```

References are automatically dereferenced, can't be `null` and makes the code clean.

Note:
In C++, references which are fields of classes should be initialized in the constructor.

```
class SomeClass {
  int& a; // This is not an uninitialized reference. It should be initialized 
          // in the constructor. Otherwise the compiler will throw an error.
public:
  SomeClass(int& b) : a(b) {} 
};
```